# Issue when using IAppBuilder.UseWebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am creating a SPA (Singe Page Application) using WebApis in ASP .NET MVC5.
For WebAPis I am using attribute routing. For requests other than Web API, I have configured a Catch-All route that maps to Home controller and Index action
Here is my code

I have the following configuration code in my StartUp.cs file

```
using System.Web.Routing;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]

namespace MyApp

{

public class Startup
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);            


        //app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); 

    }

}
}
```

My WebApiConfig.Register method is as follows

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

For routes other than WebApis, I have the following route registered

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CatchAll",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Now in the Configuration method in the StartUp class, if I uncomment this line

```
        app.UseWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
```

and try to access any route, I get this error

```
<Error>
    <Message>
    No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:17212/orders'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
    No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Why does this happen ? Is it OK to keep this line commented ?

Comment: Consider migrating to asp.net core

Comment: You are mixing configurations. `app.UseWebApi` is primarily for OWIN pipline not MVC, so when you use that setup is negates your MVC configuration as it takes over the inspection of incoming requests. If you are mixing both MVC and Web API you can safely keep that line commented.

Comment: If you can add this as answer, I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing configurations. `app.UseWebApi` is primarily for OWIN pipline not MVC, so when you use that setup is negates your MVC configuration as it takes over the inspection of incoming requests. If you are mixing both MVC and Web API you can safely keep that line commented.