# Umbraco Web API - Cookie Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.5 with an OWIN startup class.

Despite the shortcomings with using cookie auth, I'm trying to share the cookie auth between both MVC and Web API.

I have this in my OWIN startup class:

```
private static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    CookieSecureOption secureCookieOption = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest;
#if DEBUG
    secureCookieOption = CookieSecureOption.Never;
#endif

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        CookieSecure = secureCookieOption,
        CookieManager = new ChunkingCookieManager(),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
        }, PipelineStage.Authenticate);

    //configure B2C OAuth middleware
    foreach (string policy in AppSettings.B2CPolicies)
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateBearerOptionsFromPolicy(policy));
    }

    // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
}
```

This works fine as far as the Umbraco & custom MVC pages are concerned - the current user identity is available and the Umbraco helper methods work as expected.

However for Web API controllers - whether derived from UmbracoApiController or just ApiController, the current user identity on the HTTP Context is always null. I have checked the browser request being sent for to the API controllers, and the ASPNET identity cookie is included, so I'm confused as to why this doesn't translate to a user identity on the thread & httpcontext. Anyone able to shed some light on that?

> Edit: some more info on this- I tried creating my own custom cookie
>   authentication middleware and replaced the standard MS
>   CookieAuthenticationHandler with my custom implementation so that I
>   could trace the calls through it. Interestingly, for a normal MVC
>   page, the AuthenticateCoreAsync method is invoked as the page loads,
>   which successfully reads the cookie and returns a valid authentication
>   ticket. For the Web API call, the AuthenticateCoreAsync method is not
>   invoked at all before the API method is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this - it was nothing to do with OWIN, and everything to do with my Web API initialization code. I was mixing the code required for self-hosting Web API with the code required to get Web API running as part of the MVC app. Instead of IAppBuilder.UseWebApi() I should have been using GlobalConfiguration.Configure()

So the working code looks something like this:

```
public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);
}

private static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ConfigureHttpRoutes(config);

    ConfigureFormatters(config);

    //etc...
}
```

A similar issue was encountered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39746625/issue-when-using-iappbuilder-usewebapi).